# Gap between land and sky in world background (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How can i eliminate a Gap between land and sky in world background using cycles. A grey band between ground plane and where sky (noise shader combined with a sky texture) connects. Changing camera angle changes the height of horizon but then cannot look down on ground plane without changing view of sky.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post some images of this "gap" and a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: Here are 2 photos

Comment: You can use a mist pass http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/mist-that-only-erases-objects-and-not-background

Answer (score 2):

This is a deficiency of your ocean surface not curving away from you "to infinity" the way a real ocean would. Since it's instead a finite plane, it's possible to get above it and see through the area where an infinite plane should've occupied. Some possible workarounds:

1) Make the plane bigger and lower the camera angle. You may be able to minimize the gap to the point that it's not an issue.

2) If you're committed to the higher camera angle, you can use the mist pass as suggested by cegaton to cover up the horizon. You can use a mask or gradient texture in the compositor to cancel the mist pass effect in the upper part of the frame, and thus expose the sky above the gap

Comment: Thank you both. I had trouble with mist pass dealing with world bg. I tried you option of bigger plane and low angle and it helps alot.